# Moving Line Items from my Cart into an Order to checkout - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bCFWY9NtdZ0&t=1023s) to build a shop with cart functionality. The tutorial ended there though and I am a bit woefully unprepared for this next step. If anyone could give me some direction on this, I would greatly appreciate it.

I currently have products I can add as line_items to a cart. I am unable to figure out how to take those line_items from the cart and pass them into an order. After the order is saved/placed, I want to destroy the cart and start again as the order is being processed.

My guess?: take the line items from the cart as an array/hash and add it to the order, but how?

Rails 6.0.2.2
ruby 2.7.1p83 (2020-03-31 revision a0c7c23c9c) [x86_64-linux]
rbenv 1.1.2-28-gc2cfbd1

**Cart Model**

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :cart

#  has_many :order_items, dependent: :destroy
#  has_many :products, through: :order_items

#  def add_cart(cart)
#    current_cart = Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
#    current_cart.line_items
#  end

#  def total_price
#    line_items.to_a.sum { |item| item.total_price }
#  end
end
```

**CurrentCart Concern in Models**

```
module CurrentCart

  private

  def set_cart
    @cart = Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    @cart = Cart.create
    session[:cart_id] = @cart.id
  end
end
```

**LineItem Model**

```
class LineItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :cart

  def total_price
    product.price * quantity
  end
end
```

**Order Model**

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :cart

#  has_many :order_items, dependent: :destroy
#  has_many :products, through: :order_items

#  def add_cart(cart)
#    current_cart = Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
#    current_cart.line_items
#  end

#  def total_price
#    line_items.to_a.sum { |item| item.total_price }
#  end
end
```

**Cart Controller**

```
class CartsController < ApplicationController
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :invalid_cart
  #before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]
  before_action :set_cart, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /carts
  # GET /carts.json
  def index
    @carts = Cart.all
  end

  # GET /carts/1
  # GET /carts/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /carts/new
  def new
    @cart = Cart.new
  end

  # GET /carts/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /carts
  # POST /carts.json
  def create
    @cart = Cart.new(cart_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @cart.save
        format.html { redirect_to @cart, notice: 'Cart was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @cart }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @cart.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /carts/1
  # PATCH/PUT /carts/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @cart.update(cart_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @cart, notice: 'Cart was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @cart }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @cart.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /carts/1
  # DELETE /carts/1.json
  def destroy
    @cart.destroy if @cart.id == session[:cart_id]
    session[:cart_id] = nil
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Cart was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_cart
      @cart = Cart.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def cart_params
      params.fetch(:cart, {})
    end

    def invalid_cart
      logger.error "Attempt to access invalid cart #{params[:id]}"
      redirect_to root_path, notice: "That cart doesn't exist"
    end
end
```

**LineItem Controller**

```
class LineItemsController < ApplicationController
  include CurrentCart
  before_action :set_line_item, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :set_cart, only: [:create]

  # GET /line_items
  # GET /line_items.json
  def index
    @line_items = LineItem.all
  end

  # GET /line_items/1
  # GET /line_items/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /line_items/new
  def new
    @line_item = LineItem.new
  end

  # GET /line_items/1/edit
  def edit
    @line_item = LineItem.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /line_items
  # POST /line_items.json
  def create
    product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    @line_item = @cart.add_product(product)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @line_item.save
        format.html { redirect_to @line_item.cart, notice: 'Item added to cart.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @line_item }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @line_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /line_items/1
  # PATCH/PUT /line_items/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @line_item.update(line_item_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @line_item, notice: 'Item was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @line_item }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @line_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /line_items/1
  # DELETE /line_items/1.json

  def destroy
    @cart = Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
    @line_item.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to cart_path(@cart), notice: 'Item successfully removed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  def add_quantity
    @line_item = LineItem.find(params[:id])
    @line_item.quantity += 1
    @line_item.save
    redirect_to root_url
  end

  def reduce_quantity
    @line_item = LineItem.find(params[:id])
    if @line_item.quantity > 1
      @line_item.quantity -= 1
    end
    @line_item.save
    redirect_to root_url
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_line_item
      @line_item = LineItem.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def line_item_params
      params.require(:line_item).permit(:product_id)
    end
end
```

**OrderController**

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_cart, only: [:new, :create]
  before_action :set_order, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /orders
  # GET /orders.json
  def index
    @orders = Order.all
  end

  # GET /orders/1
  # GET /orders/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /orders/new
  def new
    @order = Order.new
    @order = @cart.line_items
  end

  # GET /orders/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /orders
  # POST /orders.json
  def create
    @order = Order.new(order_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @order.save
        format.html { redirect_to @order, notice: 'Order was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @order }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /orders/1
  # PATCH/PUT /orders/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @order.update(order_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @order, notice: 'Order was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @order }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /orders/1
  # DELETE /orders/1.json
  def destroy
    @order.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to orders_url, notice: 'Order was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_order
      @order = Order.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def order_params
      params.fetch(:order, {})
    end
end
```

**Schema**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2020_04_22_162713) do

  create_table "carts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

  create_table "line_items", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "product_id", null: false
    t.integer "cart_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.integer "quantity", default: 1
    t.index ["cart_id"], name: "index_line_items_on_cart_id"
    t.index ["product_id"], name: "index_line_items_on_product_id"
  end

  create_table "orders", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.integer "cart_id"
    t.index ["cart_id"], name: "index_orders_on_cart_id"
  end

  create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "product_type"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.integer "length"
    t.integer "width"
    t.decimal "price", precision: 10, scale: 2
    t.decimal "depth", precision: 3, scale: 3
  end

  create_table "themes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

  add_foreign_key "line_items", "carts"
  add_foreign_key "line_items", "products"
  add_foreign_key "orders", "carts"
end
```

**Routes**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :orders
  devise_for :users
  resources :themes
  resources :line_items
#  resources :carts
  resources :products
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

root "themes#index"

  get 'carts/:id' => "carts#show", as: "cart"
  delete 'carts/:id' => "carts#destroy"


  post 'line_items/:id/add' => "line_items#add_quantity", as: "line_item_add"
  post 'line_items/:id/reduce' => "line_items#reduce_quantity", as: "line_item_reduce"
  post 'line_items' => "line_items#create"
  delete 'line_items/:id' => "line_items#destroy"

end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend trying to seperate `Cart` and `Order` by creating another model similar to `LineItem` and call it something like `OrderItem`. This new model should have the same attributes of `LineItem` such as `product_id` and `quantity`. You will need to set up as similar `belongs_to` / `has_many` relationship here.

You need someway of determining what your current cart is through something like a `current_cart` helper stored on your session, I would recommend following this video for help on that -it will also take you away from scaffolding which may help you get more control over your code:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rPmlA_T_J84

Equipped with `current_cart` you could in the `OrdersController#create` action copy `line_items` to `order_items` over like this:

```
def create
    if @order = Order.save(order_params) # this will save the order 
       
       current_cart.line_items.each do |line_item|
          # using the bang (!) to save to the DB and raise any errors
          # rather than failing silently
          @order.order_items.create!(         
             product_id: line_item.product_id,
             quantity:   line_item.quantity 
          )
          end
    
        redirect_to @order, notice: 'Order was successfully created.'
    else
        redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Something went wrong saving the order.'
    end 
 end
```